# Pandas : one to many join + new row for balance value left : Split contract with invoices

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have two tables

dataframe contracts

```
    CtrNo  Quantity product
0  S001      -400       A
1  S002      -200       B
2  S003      -150       C
```

dataframe invoices

```
   InvNo CtrNo  Quantity ShipmentNo
0  IN001  S001        55      SH001
1  IN002  S001        45      SH002
2  IN003  S001        15           
3  IN004  S003        10      SH003
4  IN005  S002        50      SH004
5  IN006  S001        25           
6  IN007  S002        15           
7  IN008  S003        45      SH005
8  IN009  S001         5           
9  IN010  S002        10      SH006
```

the second table has the details on what has been invoiced and "Shipement" describes out of the ones that have been shipped out of the invoiced.

I need to slipt the contracts with invoiced quantities against them and then add a new row with balance quantity left. 
I am unable to do the same with pd.merge.

the output table should look like below

```
    InvNo CtrNo Product  Quantity ShipmentNo        Status
0   IN001  S001       A        85      SH001           NaN
1   IN002  S001       A        45      SH002           NaN
2   IN003  S001       A        15        NaN           NaN
3   IN006  S001       A        25        NaN           NaN
4   IN009  S001       A         5        NaN           NaN
5     NaN  S001       A       225        NaN  not invoiced
6   IN005  S002       B        50      SH004           NaN
7   IN007  S002       B        15        NaN           NaN
8   IN010  S002       B        10      SH006           NaN
9     NaN  S002       B       125        NaN  not invoiced
10  IN004  S003       C        10      SH003           NaN
11  IN008  S003       C        45      SH005           NaN
12    NaN  S003       C        95        NaN  not invoiced
```

below is the code to create the input dataframes

```
d = {'CtrNo': ['S001', 'S002','S003'], 
     'Quantity': [-400, -200 ,-150] ,
     'product': ['A' , 'B'  ,'C']}

contracts = pd.DataFrame(d)


i = {'InvNo' :["IN001","IN002","IN003",
                       "IN004","IN005","IN006","IN007","IN008","IN009","IN010"],
             'CtrNo' :["S001","S001","S001","S003",
                       "S002","S001","S002","S003","S001","S002"],
               'Quantity' :[55, 45, 15, 10, 50, 25, 15, 45, 5, 10],
        'ShipmentNo' : ["SH001","SH002","","SH003",
                       "SH004","","","SH005","","SH006"] }

invoices = pd.DataFrame(i)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `grouby sum` to sum the quantities in the `invoices` dataframe, and then combine them with the quantities in the `contracts` dataframe

Once this is done, you can concat those new lines to the invoices dataframe.

You should just take case of the additional columns (`product` and `Status`) but the general path is that. Full code could be:

```
# prepare the result dataframe by merging the product column into invoices
df = pd.merge(invoices, contracts.drop(columns='Quantity'), on='CtrNo')

# prepare the new lines (not invoiced quantities) by adding a Status column to contracts
ni = contracts.set_index('CtrNo')[['Quantity', 'product']
                                  ].assign(Status='not invoiced')

# compute the not invoiced quantities
ni['Quantity'] = - ni['Quantity'] - df.groupby('CtrNo')['Quantity'].sum()

# concat the newlines and sort
resul = pd.concat([df, ni.reset_index()], sort=False).sort_values(
    'CtrNo').reset_index(drop=True)
```

It gives:

```
    InvNo CtrNo  Quantity ShipmentNo product        Status
0   IN001  S001        55      SH001       A           NaN
1   IN002  S001        45      SH002       A           NaN
2   IN003  S001        15                  A           NaN
3   IN006  S001        25                  A           NaN
4   IN009  S001         5                  A           NaN
5     NaN  S001       255        NaN       A  not invoiced
6   IN005  S002        50      SH004       B           NaN
7   IN007  S002        15                  B           NaN
8   IN010  S002        10      SH006       B           NaN
9     NaN  S002       125        NaN       B  not invoiced
10  IN004  S003        10      SH003       C           NaN
11  IN008  S003        45      SH005       C           NaN
12    NaN  S003        95        NaN       C  not invoiced
```